# Drupal not rendering page content

Tags: php, drupal, backup

I'm trying to create a full backup of [cyclekids.org](http://cyclekids.org). I've backed up all the files, dumped the database, and restored it on another machine ([beta.cyclekids.org](http://beta.cyclekids.org)). However, Drupal doesn't seem to be rendering any page content on the backed-up site. Even pages that 404 on the regular site display the same mostly-blank template with a smattering of content.

What are likely culprits for this (e.g. misdirected theme file or broken config)?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons:

- First, upload some simple php file containing only php info function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php), call it and see is everything ok there with the server. I.e. do you have PHP enabled at all. Don't forget to delete that file when it starts working.
- If you get php info output that means that php is working. So next problem could be that because of different server settings you are getting php error, but errors are not displayed.
  Try finding in your control panel where php settings are and turn off on page error reports.
  If you can't find it in control panel, try enabling error reporting from the code: add

  error_reporting(E_ALL);

as first function in index.php file in site root.

- Check how much memory PHP has available. Upload some php info file to working site and compare difference in their output.